# how to override addproduct button of opportunity

Tags: apex, pagereference, wrapper-class, button-overrides

i want to override the addproduct button of opportunity there is one condition ie if the pricebook is selected than redirect to my vf page and if it is not selected than redirect it to choose pricebook page.
class code--

```
 oppId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        if(!string.isBlank(oppId))
            opp=[Select ID from Opportunity where Id= :oppId limit 1];

 public PageReference loadIt() {
        if(pricebookentry.pricebook2Id==null){

        pageReference newpage=new pagereference('https://login.salesforce.com/oppitm/choosepricebook.jsp?id='+oppid+'&retURL=%2F'+oppid+'&saveURL=%2F'+oppid);
        return newpage;
        }
        else{
        return null;
        }
    }
```

vf page code--

```
<apex:page StandardController="opportunity" extensions="opproductcls" id="page" action="{!loadit}">
```

Comment: Are you using standard Opportunity page layout or a custom VF page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the "Add Products" button without overriding the Pricebook selection page as well. Your VF page will need to handle picking the Pricebook prior to allowing adding products. I've used MichaelForce's starting point before: http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0G30000006eVxVEAU

Helps you get that functionality and then you can build out your own Add Products page on top.